# Maximum value of the given funtion in the given interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

What is the maximum value of $$f(t)=e^{-\sin 2t}$$ where $t\in [0,\pi/4]$

My attempt:
$$f'(t)=-2\cos 2t.e^{-\sin 2t}$$

For maxima or minima $f'(t)=0$ gives $$-2\cos 2t.e^{-\sin 2t}=0\\
\Rightarrow\cos 2t=0\\
\Rightarrow t=n\pi\pm\pi/4,n\in\Bbb Z$$
Then point of maxima or minima is $t=\pi/4$

Now I calculated $$f''(t)=2e^{-\sin 2t}[\cos^22t+\sin 2t]$$
and get that $f''(\pi/4)$ is positive

Hence $t=\pi/4$ is not a point of maximum. So please tell me what is maximum value of the function and How can I get that?

Thank you.

Comment: You have missed the fact that in the given interval it can be an increasing or a decreasing function, in which case, the minimum or maximum will be attained at the end-points. Well, in this case, as David has answered, the point is $0$.

Comment: @Shailesh yes exponential function is either increasing or decreasing. I got two methods your and David. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use calculus.  We have
$$0\le t\le\frac\pi4$$
so
$$0\le2t\le\frac\pi2$$
so
$$0\le\sin2t\le1$$
so
$$-1\le-\sin2t\le0\ .$$
The maximum value of $e^{-\sin2t}$ is $e^0=1$.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Now it looks very easy.